# How to I run a function for each piece of an array within a for loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

I have this so far, trying to get it to find the sum of each one of any number of inputted numbers with integers and "-"s.

When I run this,

```
var howM = prompt("How many cards?")

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < howM; i++)
    arr.push(prompt("Enter a card:"));

console.log(arr)

var sumpre = [];

for (var i = 0; i <= howM; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    var eXt = arr[i];
    eXt = eXt.replace(/-/g, "");
    for (i = 0; i < eXt.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(eXt.substr(i, 1));
    }
    sumpre.push(sum);
}
console.log(sumpre)
```

I have also tried

```
var howM = prompt("How many cards?")

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < howM; i++)
    arr.push(prompt("Enter a card:"));

console.log(arr)

for (var i = 0; i < howM; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    var eXt = arr[i]
    eXt = eXt.replace(/-/g, "");
    for (i = 0; i < eXt.length; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(eXt.substr(i, 1));
    }
}
console.log(sum);
```

In both cases I get the sum for the first piece in the array and then undefined. How do I get it to run for each piece? I kind of have an idea of what is wrong with it I just don't quite know how to fix it.

Comment: General tip: Make use of [indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) to improve the readability of your code.

Comment: Can you provide example data for `arr`

Comment: You are using the same `for` counter variable name (`i`) in the outer and inner loops, they all should be using their own

Comment: The `i` is getting reset on the for-loop initialization. There is no issue there.

Comment: right now im using 123-123, 234-234 and 345-345

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a second counter for the nested for loop, like so:

```
var howM = prompt("How many cards?")

var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < howM; i++)
  arr.push(prompt("Enter a card:"));

console.log(arr)

var sumpre = [];

for(var i = 0; i < howM; i++) {
  var sum = 0;
  var eXt = arr[i];
  eXt = eXt.replace (/-/g, "");
  for (var j = 0; j < eXt.length; j++) {
    sum += parseInt(eXt.substr(j, 1)); 
  }
  sumpre.push(sum);
}
console.log(sumpre)
```

Answer (score -2):

Your `var sum = 0;` inside your for-loop meaning `sum` variable will not be accessible outside of the loop

Comment: variables declared with `var` are not block scoped, like ones declared with `let`, `sum` will be visible outside the for loop

Comment: No, there is no block scoping in JavaScript (unless you use `let` or `const`)

Comment: JavaScript does not have block level scope when variables are declared with `var`. ES2015 introduces block scope with `let`. Any variable declared with `var` either has Global scope or function scope.

Comment: still a very bad practice

Comment: @Enzey That's a matter of opinion. It's often done to express that the variable has no other purpose than to be used inside of the loop.

Comment: @Enzey well, even if it is, it still means your answer is not correct.